# Make a String Variable a Class Name in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program in C++ to make schedules for me, since I have a hard time focusing on school work. The code will make priorities of assignments based on the due dates, duration to do the assignments, etc.

Anyway, I've run into a massive problem. I'm trying to assign a class variable's name to a variable! For example:

```
string a = "assignmentName" Class a(); //a is a variable and it's supposed to put the class's name as assignmentName
```

If you don't think this way will work, please tell me other solutions!

Also, I'm still a beginner, so please try to explain a little simple!

---

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Assignment
{
  private:
    int duration = 30; //Amount of time per assignment (in minutes)
    int due = 1; //Amount of days till its due, if it's one then the assignment is due in 1 days
    string name; //Name of assignment
  public:
    Assignment(int, int, string);
    ~Assignment();

    void setDuration(int duration) {this -> duration = duration;}
    void setDue(int due) {this -> due = due;}
    void setDue(int name) {this -> name = name;}

    int getDuration() { return duration; }
    int getDue() { return due; }
    string getName() { return name; }
};

Assignment::Assignment (int duration, int due, string name) //Constructor Method
{
  this -> duration = duration;
  this -> due = due;
  this -> name = name;
}

Assignment::~Assignment() //Destructor Method
{
  cout << "Assignment Object Destroyed" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int assignmentAmount;
  int i;
  int userInput1;
  int userInput2;
  string userInput3;


  cout << "Enter assignment amount: ";
  cin >> assignmentAmount << "\n" << endl;

  for (i = 0; i < assignmentAmount; i++){
    cout << "Enter assignment" << i <<"'s " << "duration: ";
    cin >> userInput1 << endl;

    cout << "Enter assignment" << i << "'s " << "due date in days from now: ";
    cin >> userInput2 >> endl;

    cout << "Enter assignment" << i <<"'s " << "name: ";
    cin >> userInput3 >> endl;

    Assignment i(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3); //I is the class's number and it's supposed to be a variable
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your specific *question* ?

Comment: I don't actually see a question here. What makes you think your code is not working?

Comment: Clarification needed, you cannot have "Assignment i" when "i" is a number variable

Comment: do you just want to create a vector of `Assignment`s?

Comment: Sorry, I need to assign a string variable to a variable name, for example, I want to assign string name = "assignment";

Comment: and then Class assignment(); but the assignment is actually a variable

Comment: @StrangeJmaster I guess you haven't learned about arrays yet, because what you seem to be describing is nothing more than declaring an array of `Assignment`'s

Comment: Your question is unclear or does not make sense. Something like this?
Assignment myassignment(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
std::string name = myassignment.name;

Comment: Unrelated: Give variable names that describes what the variable should contain and how it should be used. For example, the purpose of `userInput1`, would be better described by `duration`. Good naming allows the code to be self-descriptive, it effectively comments itself, and helps enormously when debugging.

Comment: Reminds me of my favorite talking to a student writing a program: I asked "*Why did you name that variable `X`?*", and the student replied: "*Because I don't know what's in it.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an **array** of `Assignment` objects, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
  Assignment *assignments;
  int assignmentAmount;
  int userInput1;
  int userInput2;
  string userInput3;

  cout << "Enter assignment amount: ";
  cin >> assignmentAmount << "\n" << endl;

  assignments = new Assignment[assignmentAmount];

  for (int i = 0; i < assignmentAmount; i++){
    cout << "Enter assignment " << i << "'s duration: ";
    cin >> userInput1 << endl;

    cout << "Enter assignment " << i << "'s due date in days from now: ";
    cin >> userInput2 >> endl;

    cout << "Enter assignment " << i <<"'s name: ";
    cin >> userInput3 >> endl;

    // either:
    assignments[i] = Assignment(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);

    // or:   
    assignments[i].setDuration(userInput1);
    assignments[i].setDue(userInput2);
    assignments[i].setName(userInput3);
  }

  // use assignments and assignmentAmount as needed...

  delete[] assignments;

  return 0;
}
```

Though, you should use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` directly:

```cpp
#include <vector>
...

int main()
{
  std::vector<Assignment> assignment;
  int assignmentAmount;
  int userInput1;
  int userInput2;
  string userInput3;

  cout << "Enter assignment amount: ";
  cin >> assignmentAmount << "\n" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < assignmentAmount; i++){
    cout << "Enter assignment " << i << "'s duration: ";
    cin >> userInput1 << endl;

    cout << "Enter assignment " << i << "'s due date in days from now: ";
    cin >> userInput2 >> endl;

    cout << "Enter assignment " << i << "'s name: ";
    cin >> userInput3 >> endl;

    // either:
    assignments.push_back(Assignment(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3));

    // or:
    assignments.emplace_back(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
  }

  // use assignments as needed...

  return 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <vector>
...

int main()
{
  std::vector<Assignment> assignment;
  int assignmentAmount;
  int userInput1;
  int userInput2;
  string userInput3;

  cout << "Enter assignment amount: ";
  cin >> assignmentAmount << "\n" << endl;

  assignments.resize(assignmentAmount);

  for (int i = 0; i < assignmentAmount; i++){
    cout << "Enter assignment " << i << "'s duration: ";
    cin >> userInput1 << endl;

    cout << "Enter assignment " << i << "'s due date in days from now: ";
    cin >> userInput2 >> endl;

    cout << "Enter assignment " << i << "'s name: ";
    cin >> userInput3 >> endl;

    // either:
    assignments[i] = Assignment(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);

    // or:
    assignments[i].setDuration(userInput1);
    assignments[i].setDue(userInput2);
    assignments[i].setName(userInput3);
  }

  // use assignments as needed...

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get variable names as a variable, since a variable is basically like an alias to the data, when your program gets compiled all these names, don't exist anymore.

Comment: Are there any alternatives or fixes to it though? please help

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: I also don't see why you'd do this.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not emit symbol names to the executable (the debug version may have symbol names).

If you want to *associate* or *map* symbol names to variables, you will need to declare the variable global and place the address into some kind of table.

Example:

```
int my_global_int_a;
std::map<std::string, int *> variable_dictionary;
variable_dictionary["my_global_int_a"] = &my_global_int_a;
// Here's how to get the variable
const std::string variable_name = "my_global_int_a";
int * p_variable = nullptr;
p_variable = variable_dictionary[variable_name];
std::cout << *p_variable << std::endl;
```

You may want to give deep thought to the need of retaining variable names.